# Bounding function for Travelling Salesman Problem

Tags: lower-bounds, traveling-salesman, branch-and-bound

I have been studying the Branch and Bound paradigm. I came across an approach to solve the Travelling Salesman Problem using branch and bound where a specific kind of bounding function was used. I've been wondering why this bounding function (which performs a kind of reduction on the adjacency matrix of the graph under consideration) works. Here's a link to an article describing this approach.

https://www.techiedelight.com/travelling-salesman-problem-using-branch-and-bound/

I'll illustrate the approach of evaluating this bounding function for a graph using an example graph. Following is the adjacency matrix of the graph:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\infty & 20 & 30 & 10 & 11 \\
15 & \infty & 30 & 10 & 11 \\
3 & 5 & \infty & 2 & 4 \\
19 & 6 & 18 & \infty & 3 \\
16 & 4 & 7 & 16 & \infty \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now the first step is to calculate the minimum value present in each row and to subract that value from every element in that row. In the first row, the minimum is 10. So I'll subtract 10 from every element of the first row and add store this value in a variable, x. Now x = 10.

Now the matrix becomes the following:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\infty & 10 & 20 & 0 & 1 \\
15 & \infty & 30 & 10 & 11 \\
3 & 5 & \infty & 2 & 4 \\
19 & 6 & 18 & \infty & 3 \\
16 & 4 & 7 & 16 & \infty \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I will continue this procedure for each row and I'll keep adding the minimum values of the rows to the variable x until I am done with all the rows. The resultant matrix becomes:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\infty & 10 & 20 & 0 & 1 \\
5 & \infty & 20 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 3 & \infty & 0 & 2 \\
16 & 3 & 15 & \infty & 0 \\
12 & 0 & 3 & 12 & \infty \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now the value of x is 29.

At this point we consider each column of our current matrix and see if at least one 0 exists in every column. Since the first and third columns have no 0s in them, we subtract the minimum element of first column from every element of the first column and add that value to the variable x. We do the same for the third column. Our resultant matrix is the following after completing these steps:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\infty & 10 & 17 & 0 & 1 \\
4 & \infty & 17 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 3 & \infty & 0 & 2 \\
15 & 3 & 12 & \infty & 0 \\
11 & 0 & 0 & 12 & \infty \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now the value of x is 33 and every row and column of the above matrix has atleast one 0. Hence we stop and the value stored in x i.e. 33 is our lower bound for the Travelling Salesman Problem.

Why does the reduction of the adjacency matrix (outlined above) give us a lower bound for the Travelling Salesman Problem?